# html input of type File wrapped inside ASP: Panel is not disabled when panel is disabled

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have wrapped HTML Input control of type File inside ASP:Panel control(which is wrapped inside update panel).
When I disable ASP:Panel control, input control is still enable. Please helpme out
ASPX Code :

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlBrowseCSV" runat="server" Enabled="true">
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top" style="height: 30px; width: 160px;">
              <strong>CSV File:</strong>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 30px">
               <input type="file" id="csvFile" runat="server"
               onkeydown="return false" style="width: 350px; background-color:white"/>
                &nbsp; <strong>(*.csv)</strong>&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="height: 30px">
                <ASP:Button ID="btnValidate" Text="Validate" runat="server"
                 OnClick="btnValidate_Click" />                                        
            </td>
        </tr>
   </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce what you're experiencing.  Unless someone chimes in with a better alternative, I think you will need to explicitly disable your file upload.

Answer (score 0):

Using visible attribute instead of Enabled.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlBrowseCSV" runat="server" Visible="False">
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is [by design](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/567484/fileupload-is-not-rendered-disabled-in-a-disabled-container). What you can do rather is write one extra line of code to disable File upload where you disable the panel.

```
pnlBrowseCSV.Enabled = false;
csvFile.Enabled=false;
```